# How to use the gtsam library in my ROS package?

Tags: ros, library, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently revisiting ROS as I want to build localization with the [GTSAM library](https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam/). It is important to mention that this is the first time I used an external library aside from OpenCV.

I cloned the repository into my `/usr/lib` folder and installed it as instructed.
I then added two includes into my - otherwise functioning `.h` file - and tried to compile.
The beginning of my `.h` file, the compile error and my `CMakeLists.txt` are shown below. Interestingly, if I comment out the second include and just include `Pose2.h`, compilation works. That should mean that the compiler at least finds some headers from the library, ergo it is correctly installed. The part of my `cmake` code which is supposed to link the library is extracted from an example project given [here](https://bitbucket.org/gtborg/gtsam/src/8b0c2ecaf4060965eca355bdd907d239b5124de6/cmake/example_project/CMakeLists.txt?at=develop&fileviewer=file-view-default).

**car_lib.h:**

```
#ifndef CAR_LIB_H
#define CAR_LIB_H

// GTSAM headers
#include <gtsam/geometry/Pose2.h>
#include <gtsam/nonlinear/NonlinearFactorGraph.h>
using namespace gtsam;

// rest of file follows....
```

**When compiling, I get the following error:**

```
...
[100%] Linking CXX executable /home/marc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/car/car_node
[100%] Linking CXX shared library /home/marc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libcar_lib.so
[100%] Built target car_lib
CMakeFiles/car_node.dir/src/car_node.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
/usr/local/include/gtsam/inference/Key.h:41: undefined reference to `gtsam::_defaultKeyFormatter[abi:cxx11](unsigned long)'
/usr/local/include/gtsam/inference/Key.h:52: undefined reference to `gtsam::_multirobotKeyFormatter[abi:cxx11](unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
car/CMakeFiles/car_node.dir/build.make:113: recipe for target '/home/marc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/car/car_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/marc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/car/car_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:384: recipe for target 'car/CMakeFiles/car_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [car/CMakeFiles/car_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

**My CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(car)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  geometry_msgs
  message_generation
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

###### GTSAM STUFF STARTS HERE

# Include GTSAM CMake tools
find_package(GTSAMCMakeTools)
#include(GtsamBuildTypes) # Load build type flags and default to Debug mode
#include(GtsamTesting)    # Easy functions for creating unit tests and scripts
#include(GtsamMatlabWrap) # Automatic MATLAB wrapper generation

# Ensure that local folder is searched before library folders
#include_directories(BEFORE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

###################################################################################
# Find GTSAM components
find_package(GTSAM REQUIRED) # Uses installed package
include_directories(${GTSAM_INCLUDE_DIR})

###################################################################################
# Build static library from common sources
#set(CONVENIENCE_LIB_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
#add_library(${CONVENIENCE_LIB_NAME} STATIC include/car/car_lib.h src/car_lib.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${CONVENIENCE_LIB_NAME} gtsam)

###### GTSAM STUFF ENDS HER

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES car_lib
  CATKIN_DEPENDS
  geometry_msgs
  message_runtime
  nav_msgs
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
add_library(car_lib
  include/${PROJECT_NAME}/car_lib.h
  src/car_lib.cpp
)

add_executable(car_node src/car_node)
target_link_libraries(car_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(car_lib
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263158/how-to-use-the-gtsam-library-in-my-ros-package?/) by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2017-06-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-04**:\

> fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory

this is not a problem with 'libraries', but with your compiler not being able to find `Eigen`. For starters I would add `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to your `include_directories(..)` statement. And make CMake find Eigen.

**Comment by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) on 2017-06-04**:
Oops. Did not copy that code snippet. `${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}` was part of my `CMakeLists.txt`.
How do I go about finding Eigen? The library has local copies of third party libraries, including Eigen. I have the folder `/usr/lib/gtsam/gtsam/3rdparty` . How can I make CMake find all of this?

**Comment by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) on 2017-06-04**:
maybe I installed the library in the wrong folder? I notice that - while coding - my IDE can not find the imports from it.

**Comment by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) on 2017-06-06**:
Edit: I severely changed the original text and incorporated more info and a specific case.

**Comment by [dalis](https://answers.ros.org/users/32117/dalis/) on 2017-10-02**:
did you made it work? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395859/how-to-use-the-c-library-gtsam-in-my-project-package).

---

Originally posted by [anonymous28046](https://answers.ros.org/users/28046/anonymous28046/) with karma: 65 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0